# NLA and animation properties

Tags: interface, 3d-view, blender-internal-render-engine, theme

I am watching a tuto on NLA doing on blender 2.66. I have the 2.72 version. I can not found the complete  properties  of animation in the NLA window (image2) as in the 2.66 version (image1).

[image: image1]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the pushdown action button (icon with the double down arrows):

[image]

After that the *Action Strip* settings become available in the *Properties*

[image]

This is documented in the [Docs Creating Action Strips](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Animation/Editors/NLA)